# Correct PHP for a 404 redirect?

Tags: php, url-rewriting, url-routing, http-status-code-404

I have to use custom 404 page for url redirection (.htaccess is not an option). I'm thinking of using the code below. I'm trying to account for valid redirection, and for the real case of a page not found, by adding a flag to the URL. What do you think?

```
<?php

// check GET for the flag - if set we've been here before so do not redirect

if (!isset($_GET['rd'])){
    // send a 200 status message
    header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 200 Ok');
    // redirect
    $url = 'new-url/based-on/some-logic.php' . '?rd=1';
    header('Location: ' . $url);
    exit;
}

// no redirection - display the 'not found' page...
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>404:</h1>
<h3>Sorry, the page you have requested has not been found.</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit** - the reason .htaccess is not an option is because I'm running on IIS6 without apache.

Comment: @hakre: o.O Struggling to parse that, buddy.

Comment: Are you really sure you want to redirect to an existing file within a 404 error handler for nice URLs? That would not mimic URL rewriting. @tomalak: thx for the hint.

Comment: You can use [ISAPI_Rewrite 3](http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/) which will bring mod_rewrite support via .htaccess to your IIS6 server. It has Light version which is free.

Answer (score 4):

Add 404 [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) generation:

```
...
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
// for FastCGI: header("Status: 404 Not Found");
// no redirection - display the 'not found' page...
?>
...
```

And remove 200 code:

```
// delete this line
header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 200 Ok');
// because code should be 302 for redirect
// and this code will be generated with "Location" header.
```

Comment: The 404 header is already added by apache as the script get's invoked by the error handler. But maybe PHP will convert it into 2xx. Ok. But Removing the 200 status looks superfluous to me. It will get removed by PHP as the location header is fired next line. And PHP will make the status 302 then. See the manual: php.net/manual/en/function.header.php - So why do you remove the 200 header? It does not make sense in my eyes.

Comment: @hakre, line with adding `200 OK` status - that what is superfluous , because next line (with `Location`) will override this status. Please, don't tell me `see the manual`, if you can't understand something in the answer.

Comment: just linking for convenience but I see it got broken.

Comment: guys, I don't have apache running, I'm on IIS6, hence the use of 404 redirects. @OZ_ This exercise is about trying to mimic mod_rewrite and so that's why I want to give a 200 instead of 302 or 301. Is that bad?

Comment: @Owen, redirection can not exist without 302 (`30x`) code, so your 200 code will be just overridden by PHP. Also, if you really trying to mimic mod_rewrite behavior, you should redirect to `index.php`, when you can't find the page, without 'Not found' message and 404 code.

Answer (score 0):

IF i am not getting you wrong, you want a Page to be shown for the 404 pages, that is, pages which do not exist anymore.

to the best of my knowledge (might be not too much) You cannot just set a php page as 404 handler without .htaccess or the apache conf file.

what i remember is that a 404.shtml is the default file for 404 handlers in normal apache setups, so you will need to put your code in that page,

and since you cannot use .htaccess and the page is SHTML, you cannot put php in that, you a Javascript Redirection from 404.shtml to your 404.php might do the trick,

Hope that helps.

Comment: On some servers you can not make use of Mod_Rewrite but you can set the error page and point it to a PHP script. The PHP script then takes care about the "rewrite", the mapping to nice URLs.

Comment: I don't have the luxury of apache - I've edited the original question - sorry for leaving out that, and thanks for your contribution.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that you do not want to redirect but to include the page in question. The redirect is not necessary. Infact it will undermine to use the apache 404 error handler for nice urls.

The following example script does first resolve the request to a (relative) filename, the module. In your code that would be `new-url/based-on/some-logic.php` or similar.

Next to that, if a module is not found, an error page template will be used instead. I have named it `error404.php` so you would additionally need to create that file.

As a last resort, if even no error template is found, a standard 404 error message will be returned.

```
<?php

// === resolver ===

// put your logic in here to resolve the PHP file,
// return false if there is no module for the request (404).
function resolveModule() {
  // return false;
  return 'new-url/based-on/some-logic.php';
}

// returns the filename of a module
// or false if things failed.
function resolveFile($module) {
    $status = 200;
    if (false === $module) {
        $status = 404;
        $module = 'error404.php';
    }
    // modules are files relative to current directory
    $path = realpath($module); 
    if (!file_exists($path)) {
        // hard 404 error.
        $status = 404;
        $path = false;
    }
    return array($path, $status);
}

// process the input request and resolve it
// to a file to load.
$module = resolveModule();
list($path, $status) = resolveFile($module);

// === loader ===

// send status message
header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' ' . $status, true, $status);

if (false !== $path) {
    include($path); // include module file (instead of redirect)
} else {
    // hard 404 error, e.g. the error page is not even found (misconfiguration)
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>404:</h1>
<h3>Sorry, the page you have requested has not been found.</h3>
<p>Additionally the good looking error page is not available, so it looks really sad.</p>
</body>
</html>
<?
}
```

Comment: Silly `include` can't replace URL calling. At least because path in URL not always can be mapped to the path to script. Also, URL-router should be called (in MVC model), mod-rewrite can be used, params in URL can be used... Don't do it, never.

Comment: @OZ - I actually think this is a fair solution. I don't see why including the file, instead of redirecting, is a big problem - and in that case a 200 status would be fine I think. My script is for a Wordpress installation and most solutions I've seen for Wordpress on II6 without apache do include instead of redirect.

Comment: @Owen Don't do it, it's really big problem. Read my comment one more time. `include` can never replace redirection to the URL. It's just absolutely different things.

Comment: @Owen: Wordpress is able to work as a 404 handler already, you don't need to add it AFAIK. Set the error page to index.php. Should work. Ref: http://chrisjohnston.org/2009/setting-up-a-wordpress-blog-on-lighttpd (which is lighttpd but I think you can use other servers as well) - you can then make use of the rewrite API in wordpress.

Comment: @hakre - thanks for the link, even though I can't see how the Wordpress index.php can handle 404s. I'll test it.

Comment: @Owen: It's build into wordpress. I remember some code to resolve the PATHINFO on 404's. It's not fully officially documented but in. See as well http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks for other alternatives and a bunch of links.